# Is the stack frame to this code missing or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Based on what I know. When a function is called, a stack frame should be created which tracks all names and bindings within the functions. The screenshot and code are from 《Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python》offered by MIT 6.0001. [image: The nested scope]

```
def f(x):
   def g():
      x = 'abc'
      print('x =', x)
   def h():
      z = x
      print('z =', z)
   x = x + 1
   print('x =', x)
   h()
   g()
   print('x =', x)
   return g

x = 3
z = f(x)
print('x =', x)
print('z =', z)
z()
```

The 7 columns are well understood. In the last line of the code, there is a `z()` statement. This statement invokes the function returned by f, which is named g within f. Since an invocation happens, why a new stack frame is not created as there is a variable x that actually binds to ‘abc’ in the function returned?

Comment: What does the figure show?

Comment: The figure is the history of the stack frames associated with the code is depicted

Comment: What does the numbers 1 to 7 represent?

Comment: @Björn Lindqvist Okay, okay for example, column 1 represented the original phase, while f is called a stack frame is created, including names with x binds with number 3, z binds objects returned by f, and f itself as a function. Basically, when a function is called, a new symbol table is created(a stack frame), which tracks all names and current bindings within the function(including formal parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, calling `z()` also involves creation of a new stack frame. I think the image is simply not concerned with this invocation. Apparently, the seven columns only relate to the line `z = f(x)`:

```
column | 
-------+-------------------
     1 | before calling f
     2 | inside f, before calling h
     3 | inside h
     4 | inside f, after returning from h, before calling g
     5 | inside g
     6 | inside f, after returning from g
     7 | after returning from f
```